# Inheritance from inner class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I implemented a binary search tree in C++, and now I'm trying to inherit from it.

The base tree:

```
#ifndef TREE_HPP
#define TREE_HPP

class tree {
public:
    class node {
    public:
        virtual int foo() { return 1; }

        node() = default;
        virtual ~node() = default;
    };
    node* root;
    tree() : root(new node) {}
    virtual ~tree() { delete root; }
};

#endif
```

Derived tree:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_TREE_HPP
#define DERIVED_TREE_HPP

#include "tree.hpp"

class derivedTree : public tree {
public:
    class derivedNode : public node {
    public:
        virtual int foo() { return 2; }
    };
};
#endif
```

Main:

```
#include "derivedTree.hpp"
#include "tree.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main() {
    tree t1;
    derivedTree t2;
    cout << "Hey! " << t1.root->foo() << "\n";
    cout << "Hey! " << t2.root->foo() << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
Hey! 1
Hey! 1
```

I expect it to be 1 and 2.
I think it's because `root` is a pointer to the base tree, and thus calls `tree::foo()`. How can I inherit from the tree, so it contains derived nodes?

Comment: you never create a `derivedNode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What virtual methods do is enable you to call your method based on the actual class instantiated instead of the type of the pointer.

So in your case, `root->foo()` would call the method based on the actual class, and not always call the `node` implementation.

To call the `derivedNode` implementation though, you have to instantiate it! As it is right now, your `derivedTree` is using the base constructor of `tree` which directly instantiate a `node`, so both `derivedTree` and `tree` will have a `node` object as `root`!

To solve the problem, as already shown in other answers, you can add to `tree` a constructor that takes an external `node` pointer and use that constructor in the constructor of `derivedTree`, to initialize `root` with a pointer to a `derivedTree`.

Like this: ([runnable link](https://ideone.com/QxLLEc))

```
class tree {
public:
    class node {
    public:
        virtual int foo() { return 1; }

        node() = default;
        virtual ~node() = default;
    };
    node* root;
    tree(): root(new node) {};
    tree(node* d) : root(d) {}; // here we initialize the root pointer with a given pointer
    virtual ~tree() { delete root; };
};

class derivedTree : public tree {
public:
    class derivedNode : public node {
    public:
        virtual int foo() { return 2; }
    };
    derivedTree(): tree(new derivedNode) {}; // here we use the added constructor to create a derivedNode and set it as root
};

using std::cout;

int main() {
    tree t1;
    derivedTree t2;
    cout << "Hey! " << t1.root->foo() << "\n";
    cout << "Hey! " << t2.root->foo() << "\n";
}
```

Note that it is not possible to initialize `root` directly in the derived constructor, because the language allows to put in the initializer list only fields of the actual class and not derived fields and depending on the compiler you would risk of creating a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another constructor taking pointer of type `node*` for `tree`, and initialize `root` with the parameter. Then you can pass the appropriate pointer. E.g.

```
class tree {
public:
    ...
    tree(node* r) : root(r) {}
};

class derivedTree : public tree {
public:
    ...
    derivedTree() : tree(new derivedNode) {}
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bu7F9ww38VibAPYU)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is not with inheritance, but with your `tree` object that instanciate `node` object and not your `derivedNode`.

I would use templates for this, something along those lines :

```
template <typename NodeType>
class treeT {
public:

    NodeType* root;
    tree() : root(new NodeType) {}
    virtual ~tree() { delete root; }
};

class node {
public:
    virtual int foo() { return 1; }
    node() = default;
    virtual ~node() = default;
};

class derivedNode : public node {
public:
    virtual int foo() { return 2; }
};

using tree = treeT<node>;
using derivedTree = treeT<derivedNode>;
```

If you really want inner class, you can use a kind of CRTP, but I guess it would be over-engineering.

Note that @songyuanyao also has a nice solution to this. I can't really give you a rationale for choosing one solution or the other.